# how can I use constructor method with react navigation v3?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I need to use state on my App.js code but react-navigation v3 don't use class so I can't define the constructor method.
Is there any other way so I can use state?

I tried to use a boolean javascript variable but it didn't help.

I use StackNavigator, drawer navigator and DrawerNavigator and BottomTabNavigator like this

```
const TabAppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Posts: {
    screen: PostsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Posts',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="md-home" color={tintColor} size={25} />)
    }
  },
  Tools: {
    screen: ToolsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Tools',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="md-apps" color={tintColor} size={25} />)
    }
  },
  Favourite: {
    screen: FavouriteScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Favourite',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="md-heart" color={tintColor} size={25} />)
    }
  },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Posts',
    order: ['Posts', 'Tools', 'Favourite'],
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#d94854',
      inactiveTintColor: '#818181',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderTopColor: '#818181',
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        paddingBottom: 5,
        paddingTop: 15,
      },
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 13,
        marginTop: 10,
      },
    },
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
          headerTitle: 'Growth Hack Toolkit',
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#d94854',
          },
          headerLeft: (
            <Icon name="md-menu" color="#fff" size={25} style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
          ),
          headerRight: (
            <Icon name="md-search" color="#fff" size={25} style={{ paddingRight: 15 }} onPress={() => search()} />
          )
        }
    }
  }
)

const PostsStackAppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  TabAppNavigator: TabAppNavigator,
  Posts: { screen: PostsScreen },
  Post: { screen: PostScreen }
})

const ToolsStackAppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  TabAppNavigator: TabAppNavigator,
  Tools: { screen: ToolsScreen },
  Tool: { screen: ToolScreen },
  ToolList: { screen: ToolListScreen },
  Web: { screen: WebScreen },
  Mobile: { screen: MobileScreen },
})

const DrawerAppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Posts: { screen: PostsStackAppNavigator },
  Tools: { screen: ToolsStackAppNavigator },
  About: { screen: AboutScreen },
}, {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: 250,
  })

const App = createAppContainer(DrawerAppNavigator);
export default App;
```

I want to change my header view based on my state

basically, I have a default header (the same header for all tab screens) that contains a title, menu icon to open the drawer navigation and search icon to start searching 
what I need to do is that when search icon is pressed I will change my state to show the  instead of the title and when close icon is pressed I will change the state to show my default header again.

Answer (score 0):

after spending so much time searching for a solution or a workaround, the answer is: I cannot.

It is not possible to have state in a functional component. So I have to use react navigation v2 instead of v3 as it is implemented as class-based component.

These links could help to understand:

[difference between functional and class-based React components](https://ozmoroz.com/2018/08/react-functional-vs-class-components/)

[React State without Constructor](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-without-constructor/)